# Linux Kernel Module Compilation

Tags: c, linux, makefile, linux-kernel

I am having trouble building helloworld Linux kernel module. I am using VirtualBox from SUN with Ubuntu ISO image that I downloaded from Ubuntu web site. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Bellow are the c code and the error message that I am getting:

The module file is called hellowrld.c and it contains the code below:

```
    #include <linux/module.h>    // included for all kernel modules
    #include <linux/kernel.h>    // included for KERN_INFO
    #include <linux/init.h>      // included for __init and __exit macros

    MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");

    static int __init helloworld_init(void)
    {
        printk(KERN_INFO "Hello world!\n");
        return 0;    
    }

    static void __exit helloworld_exit(void)
    {
        printk(KERN_INFO "Cleaning up module.\n");
    }

    module_init(helloworld_init);
    module_exit(helloworld_exit);
```

The make file is called makefile.c and it contains the code below:

```
    obj -m += helloworld.o

    all:
         make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules

    clean:
          make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

The error message that I am getting when I run make command is below:

```
cc    makefile.c -o makefile
makefile.c:1:4: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '-' token 
obj-m helloworld.o

make: *** No targets specified no makefile found. Stop
```

Comment: I think the problem is on the make file.

Comment: 2 seconds after there is the answer.

Comment: The makefile should *not* have a `.c` extension.  On Linux, it is convenient to have no extension at all.  Call it `Makefile` or `makefile`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

---

The right Makefile looks like this ...

```
obj-m    := helloworld.o

KDIR    := /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build
PWD    := $(shell pwd)

default:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) SUBDIRS=$(PWD) modules

clean:
    rm -rf *.o *.ko *.mod.* *.symvers *.order
```

---

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. It is now compiling as expected. Without your help, I would not have resolved this issue tonight.

Comment: @Honore if this answer solve your problem then accept this answer by clicking tick on left of the answer

Comment: @shami Thank you for letting me know.

Comment: @Knud Larsen. 
I used the same makefile. I am getting an error as `missing seperator`

Comment: Missing seperator : You have two lines which must begin with a [TAB] : `$(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) SUBDIRS=$(PWD) modules` and `rm -rf *.o *.ko *.mod.* *.symvers *.order` .... I.e. [space] [space] ... won't do for a Makefile.